# ¿Cómo obtener valor de un radio? PHP

Tags: php, html, radio

Tengo un **panel de administración** del cliente para escribir **opiniones**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vemos en la captura de pantalla, **tengo 3 opiniones**, una para la reserva de la cabaña 1 y dos para la reserva de la cabaña 3.

**¿Cómo sé yo seleccionando el radio que desee, que hago referencia a la cabaña 1(si selecciono el primer radio) o a la cabaña 3(si selecciono el segundo o tercer radio)?**

Porque a la hora de integrarlo a la función **insertarOpinionPorReserva** necesito el valor del **$idcabana.**

**Código:**

```
<?php
    require_once "Clases/BD.php";
    require_once "Clases/Opiniones.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();
    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del cliente</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "Bienvenido ".$cliente."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='reservar.php?salir=1'>Salir</a>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="menu_cliente">
                    <?php
                    //Si pulsamos el link "Nueva opinión"...
                    if(isset($_GET["nueva"])){
                        //Llamamos al método "obtenerReservasPorCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro del email del cliente.
                        $reservas = BD::obtenerReservasPorCliente($cliente);
                        echo "<form action='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1' name='form_add_opinion' id='form_add_opinion' method='POST'>";
                        $selected = true;
                        foreach ($reservas as $reserva){
                            $idreserva = $reserva["idreserva"];
                            $idcabana = $reserva["idcabana"];
                            $idemail = $reserva["idemail"];
                            $check_in = new DateTime($reserva["check_in"]);
                            $check_out = new DateTime($reserva["check_out"]);
                            $reserva_toString = "Reserva de la cabaña ".$idcabana. " | ".$idemail. " | ".$check_in->format('d/m/Y'). " | ".$check_out->format('d/m/Y')."<br/><br/>";
                            echo "<input type='radio' name='a_anadir' value='".$reserva["idreserva"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$reserva_toString."</input>";
                            $selected = false;
                        }
                        echo "<br/>Deja tu opinión: <br/>";
                        echo "<textarea rows='4' cols='56' id='texto_opinion' name='texto_opinion'></textarea><br/>";

                        echo "<p class='valoracion'>";
                            echo "<input id='radio1' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='5'>";
                            echo "<label for='radio1'>★</label>";
                            echo "<input id='radio2' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='4'>"; 
                            echo "<label for='radio2'>★</label>";
                            echo "<input id='radio3' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='3'>"; 
                            echo "<label for='radio3'>★</label>";
                            echo "<input id='radio4' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='2'>"; 
                            echo "<label for='radio4'>★</label>";
                            echo "<input id='radio5' type='radio' name='estrellas' value='1'>"; 
                            echo "<label for='radio5'>★</label>";   
                        echo "</p>";

                        echo "<input type='submit' value='Añadir opinion' name='add_opinion' id='add_opinion'>";
                        echo "</form>";
                    }

                    //Si pulsamos el botón "Añadir opinion"...
                    if(isset($_POST["add_opinion"])){
                        $idemail = $cliente;
                        $idcabana = $idcabana;
                        $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
                        $fecha = new DateTime();
                        $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
                        $valoracion = $_POST["estrellas"];
                        BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Adjunto la función: **obtenerReservasPorCliente($idemail)**, el $idemail le cogemos de la sesión del usuario.

```
static public function obtenerReservasPorCliente($idemail){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE idemail='$idemail';";
        $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
        //Creamos un array para almacenar las reservas.
        $misreservas = array();
        //Recorremos el array y añadimos en él las misreservas mediante array_push.
        while($datos = $registro->fetch()){
            //Al array $misreservas le pasamos $datos.
            array_push($misreservas, $datos);
        }
        //Devuelve el array $misreservas (asociativo).
        return $misreservas; 
    }
```

**En resumen necesito obtener "el valor del círculo rojo" de cada input de tipo radio para agregárselo a la variable $idcabana.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente el `input` devuelve el valor que le das en el atributo `value`. Por ende, en el `$_POST` debería existir el valor dentro de `$_POST["a_anadir"]` que debería devolver alguno de los valores de la variable `$reservas`.

**Dentro de tu código:**

```
if (isset($_POST["a_anadir"])) {
  $idemail = $cliente;
  $idcabana = $_POST["a_anadir"];
  $opinion = $_POST["texto_opinion"];
  $fecha = new DateTime();
  $fecha_hoy = $fecha->format ('Y/m/d');
  $valoracion = $_POST["estrellas"];
  BD::insertarOpinionPorReserva($idemail, $idcabana, $opinion, $fecha_hoy, $valoracion);
}
```

**EDIT:**

En la línea que imprimís el radio estás asignado al `value` el id de la reserva y deberías asignar el id de la cabaña, por eso es que no coincide.

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='a_anadir' value='".$reserva["idreserva"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$reserva_toString."</input>";
# y esto es lo que deberías asignar: $reserva["idcabana"]
echo "<input type='radio' name='a_anadir' value='".$reserva["idcabana"]."' ".($selected?"checked":"").">".$reserva_toString."</input>";
```

Comment: No es del todo correcto, debido a que algunos coinciden pero no debería ser así: Por ejemplo, el primer radio tiene el valor 1 que coincide con la cabaña 1, pero el segundo radio tiene el valor 2 que NO coincide con la cabaña 3. Edité la captura, necesito obtener el valor en rojo de cada radio.

Comment: Ah, ya veo el error, en donde imprimís el `input` le pusiste como `value` el valor de `$reserva["idreserva"]` y deberías poner el de `$reserva["idcabana"]`. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: Cierto. Funciona correctamente.